# Mapping values to objects in R

Tags: r

I have a question about the best implementation of mapping in R. For example, I have 10 models and 300 stocks that I need to process using those models. Each stock is represented by a symbol and will need to be processed by one of the models. I'd like to have a map that would allow me to get the model given a symbol. For example IBM,AAPL,MSFT are processed by model M1. F,GM,CAT by M2, etc... Is there a way to do something like
Model = XXX(Symbol)

Models are large and I would not want to have a list with 290 duplicates of my 10 models, so I would need to have some form of access by reference with only 10 models actually allocated.

Comment: If you now try to express that in terms of sample code and what you want to achieve, that would be awesome :)

Comment: This is a java version:`
Map<String, Model> modmap = new HashMap<String, Model> ();
Model m1 = new Model(.....);
modmap.put("IBM", m1);
modmap.put("AAPL",m1);
...
String Symbol = "IBM" ;
Model m = modmap.get(Symbol)
'

I'd like to be able to create that modmap and pull models out of it once I have the Symbol and then use them to process stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a data frame with your stocks and the associated model number:

```
mapping <- data.frame(stock=c("IBM", "AAPL", "MSFT", "F", "GM", "CAT"),
                      model=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))
```

You can look up the model number for a given stock with standard indexing:

```
mapping$model[mapping$stock == "AAPL"]
# [1] 1
```

A slightly simpler syntax would be with a named vector:

```
mapping2 <- c(IBM=1, AAPL=1, MSFT=1, F=2, GM=2, CAT=2)
mapping2["AAPL"]
# AAPL 
#    1
```

If you had a list of models called `mods`, you could use this index to look up the appropriate model for your stock:

```
mods[[mapping$model[mapping$stock == "AAPL"]]]
mods[[mapping2["AAPL"]]
```